# ArcMap: Raster layers, how to extract information

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcmap, arcgis-10.2, geology

I have several raster layers which represent particular geological formations.

Each layer is a raster dataset in a grey scale. Each cell has a pixel value which is an elevation of the bottom of a particular geological formation. Each cell also has a stretched value which is a thickness of a particular geological formation.

For each location, I would like to have the type of geological formation at each depths. Let's say, at 1 m depth step.

How can this be done? Can I somehow extract the information about layers into a csv file? Or can some manipulations be done in ArcMap?

Comment: Can be done.  You also need dem though

Comment: @FelixIP Thanks! Very encouraging! Can you please let me know a bit more details?

Answer (score 1):

I don’t have your grey layers. So I generated them:
[image]

Bottom of Sandstone increases downwards from 0 to 342, similar with basalt (East-West)

For all 3 bottoms compute vert. distance to slice level (DEM-depth), set as flat surface=100 m in this example:
[image]

Find minimum of distances

[image]

Calculate if bottom of Clay is closest to slice

[image]

Do the same for sandstone and basalt, using 2 and 3 accordingly

Mosaic results:

[image]

Result:

[image]

Comment: thank you so much for the answer! I will try it and let you know if it worked for me.

Comment: Thank you very much again for this example! I am still working though it... Here is how my data looks like: http://imgur.com/qWIEYjK and http://imgur.com/eSlTzoB. I think that that the pixel value is an elevation about the sea level. Do you know what stretched value might represent? Or can it be just not useful information.

Comment: I have quite a few different materials, around 64. All materials have the elevation of the bottom value. Hence, I cannot figure out how to find the level of the surface at each point.

Comment: I did some reading and downloaded dem_europe layer from ERSI online. This suppose to be surface elevation layer

Comment: FelixIP, your answer taught me a lot. Thanks again! I am just wondering if you had 64 different materials and some of them are not present in a particular spot, would you still use ArcGIS to do the calculations? Or would you choose to extract data into e.g. Python, than do the required calculations?

Comment: I guess the best place for you to start is Extract Multi Values to Points (Spatial Analyst)

Comment: Thank you again FelixIP. I think this is a great idea and it should work for me!